# Function equivalent to percentile in impala

Tags: sql, impala, percentile

Is there a function equivalent to Hive's 'percentile' function in Impala? I am basically trying to find the percentiles for a set of rows in my table.
I tried using percentile function with my query in Hive but it takes a lot of time to execute the query and return the result.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I post an answer. Gordon Linoffs answer provides a very nice solution. If there is only one element in a partition (cnt = 1), the percentile returns NULL. In case one wants to have the value of that single element returned, a small extension of Gordons solution might help. (The code snippet also contains partitions over a column).

```
select group_column,
   max(case when (cnt > 1 and seqnum <= p * cnt) or cnt = 1 then XXX end) 
   as percentile 
from (select t.*,
         row_number() over (partition by group_column order by XXX) as seqnum,
         count(*) over (partition by group_column) as cnt
  from t) a
group by group_column
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery and arithmetic.  For instance:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when seqnum <= p * cnt then XXX end) over () as percentile
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by XXX) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff. I get the error "AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?): row_number() OVER (ORDER BY day1diff ASC) seqnum" when i try to execute the innermost query.

Comment: @PushpaGadde . . . That is a strange error message.  There is no aggregation in this query.

Comment: I believe that max and count are considered aggregation. https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_aggregate_functions.html#aggregate_functions